# How To Pass Form Data from One Page To Another using FlaskApp

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-appbuilder

i have a form "form.html" where user can fill his information like name, address, mobile no, and image.  and i have three html pages "info.html", "success.html" and "failure.html"

i am asking for payment from the user so info.html will show the information filled by user, and later he will make payment if payment is successfull user will be redirected to "success.html", and if payment is failed, user will be redirected to "failure.html"

all three pages are same, just one line is different that is payment status "pending" or "success"

i am able to print user filled information to "info.html" but  i want to print same information on success.html or failure.html if needed.

**routes.py :**

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
  global onlineAppForm, data
  onlineAppForm = RegForm()
  name = request.form['name'].strip()
  father = request.form['father_name'].strip()  
  mother = request.form['mother_name'].strip()
  address1 = request.form['txtAddress1'].strip()
  data = {'name' : name, 'father' : father, 'mother' : mother, 'address1' : address1}
  return render_template("apply1.html", data=data, form=onlineAppForm)
```

i tryied to do this, but of course it will not work. so how should i do it.

```
@app.route('/success')
def success():
  return render_template('success.html', data=data, form=onlineAppForm)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Just read the question once again please, problem is i can print user information to info.html page, but i want to pass the same information to success.html page. So how do i do it

Comment: by making a `post` call to those pages with the same user information. Where are you storing the info?

Comment: M storing the info in "data" variable.

Comment: You need to store the info in some kind of database or something because each case should be decoupled from other. Once you are trying to fill the info. Second the user makes payment . third on the basis of success or failure you render the particular template. First of all how are you ensuring which user made the payment there is no `id` are you matching `names`. The last one thing you can do is pass that `data` in every request or every endpoint

Comment: There is message flashing: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to setup a database using SQLAlchemy and create a model. A form simply collects the data you need to create the model. Here is a walkthrough of the steps.

1. Form submitted to endpoint
2. Create instance of Model and load with form data
3. Save to db and redirect to success page (pass identifier of object)
4. query object on success route and pass to template for rendering

I have written out an example that I believe covers what you need. Didn't feel like writing the templates but I am fairly confident it should work.

http://hastebin.com/puputugune.py

also check https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for more help

**EDIT**

on template you can access your model attributes just like you would in your view.

```
<!-- success.html -->
<ul>
    <li>{{ person.id }}</li>
    <li>{{ person.first_name }}</li>
    <li>{{ person.last_name }}</li>
    <li>{{ person.email }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, that really helped me to understand things.

Comment: No problem. Check out Flask Web Development by Miguel Grinberg. Thats how I learned flask
blog.miguelgrinberg.com

Comment: Note that you don't need neccessary SQLAlchemy, but any kind of persistant data storage is enough, e.g. redis, a file, some webserve, ... . But ofcourse SQLAlchemy is normally an excellent choice, although for webpages with many users I would recommend postgresql as a backend (which is harder to set up than sqlite).

Comment: what @syntonym said is also true